# How to get xcode default images

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uibutton, accessoryview

I would like to found iOS default images (like checkmark, info icon,...) so that I can use them elsewhere and not only in cell accessory field or buttons.

I guess, that xcode must have some folder with it's resources on disk, so I would need to access that, or some other way how can I use those images inside UIImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imagery is in iOS. It is not generally accessible. You need to provide your own imagery.

Comment: So how to you get the default icons, compose, share, etc that a lot of apps use, do you have to make them or can you call it with some chunk of code? (If code, please swift) Thanks!

Comment: Make your own or buy some.  I use icons8.com

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thanks for the link I will be using it! That's funny that apple doesn't provide a set of standard icons though, wouldn't that make all the apps on iOS look more uniform?

Answer (score 1):

those images are included in the SDKs. there are many "icon extractor" projects out there. maybe that's what you are looking for:

https://github.com/devcxm/iOS-Images-Extractor

https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor

https://github.com/Marxon13/iOS-Asset-Extractor

not sure about possible legal issues though...

Answer (score 0):

SF Symbols now provides access to a lot of these system images (and lots more besides).